# React component rendering data twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

[image]I’m new to react and I’m currently facing an issue. 
I want to make a conditional rendering such that if the `URL` contains a particular id I render something else but my components seems to be doing basically everything multiple times if this condition is met. Below is my code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import DriverList from './DriverList';
import './Drivers.css';
import getDrivers from '../../Helpers/fetchAny';

function Drivers(props) {
  const url = window.location.href.split('/');
  const last = url.length - 1;
  const urlPattern = /([\d\w]*[-]).*/g;
  const id = url[last];
  const [driverState, setDriverState] = useState({ name: 'Hello' 
});
  const [toDisplayState, setToDisplayState] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getDrivers('/api/drivers').then(data => {
      setDriverState(data);
    });
  }, []);

  if (!urlPattern.test(url)) {
    return (
      <div className="mainBody drivers">
        <div className="driver-display" />
        <DriverList />
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Hello</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Drivers;
```

The question is if this condition is not met, it renders what it’s supposed to normally not repeating anything but once (normal) when the condition is met.

**The  component**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import getDrivers from '../../../Helpers/getDrivers';

import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function DriverList() {
  const [driverState, setDriverState] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    getDrivers().then(data => {
      let driverDetails = [];

      for (const driver of data) {
        driverDetails.push({
          driverId: driver.driverID,
          driverName: driver.name,
          driverPhone: driver.phone,
        });
      }
      setDriverState(driverDetails);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="driver-list">
      <p className="list-head">Drivers</p>
      {driverState.map((driver, index) => {
        return (
          <Link
            to={`/drivers/${driver.driverId}`}
            className="single-list"
            key={index}
          >
            <span className="list-image" />
            <div>
              <span>
                <i className="mdi mdi-account" /> {driver.driverName}
              </span>
              <span>
                <i className="mdi mdi-phone" /> {driver.driverPhone}
              </span>
            </div>
          </Link>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default DriverList;
```

This shows the list of drivers

Comment: Could you show what is inside your DriverList component ?

Comment: @ridoansaleh I made the edit already

Comment: But even when i do this without the DriverList it still shows twice

Comment: Yes, that's normal because you call setToDisplayState to update class state which cause the second render. Try to remove it, it will render once. Ofcourse your data will be empty. Just for your understanding purpose.

Comment: @ridoansaleh Thanks i fixed it. The issue was from my `App.js` Route, aparently, i had a route leading to that same page.

Comment: YOu're calling getDrivers twice and setting the state twice. Set the state once and pass it along components.

Answer (score -1):

So apparently, I had repeated the route to that page in my `App.js`

```
<Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
<Route path="/dashboard" component={Home} />
<Route path="/trips" component={Trips} />
<Route path="/drivers" component={Drivers} />
<Route path="/drivers:driverId” component={Drivers} />
```

All I had to do was remove onE of the `routes`.

My understanding from this is that `react` renders`when you visit a`route` in a SPA (single page application)